# Maximum value of $5\sin(200\pi t) + 7\sin(1500\pi t)$ (different frequencies)

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

> How can I find the maximum value of $5\sin(200\pi t) + 7\sin(1500\pi t)$?

I have tried differentiating to find the maxima, but that is not solvable manually. Is there any common method that can be applied for $n$ terms?

Comment: @Moo Is there a human-friendly way to solve this? :)

Comment: draw this function, how would you find the maxima?

Comment: Hey you could take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711653/max-of-sum-of-sinusoids-with-arbitrary-frequencies). Hope it helps.

Comment: @Cindy Thanks! With Newton Raphson, I found that.